# SQL Gaps and Island problem with a twist -- reset a flag based on duration from previous flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a data set of calls with Call date from customers and the outcome of the call (Status). I would like to pay my sales rep for each sold call if the most recent previous paid call has been >= 5 days.

Below is my sample data set with the table I have. Also, attached is the picture of the table with the columns I have and column I want. Colored records are sold calls; green records are ones I want to way and the red are ones I wouldn't want to pay even if it is a sold call.

[image: Image of Data Table with Have and want columns]

I have tried a few versions using window functions but haven't yet been successful. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @have TABLE
(
    CallDate DATE,
    Status VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @have (CallDate, Status)
values
('2019-01-01', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-02', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-04', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-08', 'sold'),
('2019-01-09', 'sold'),
('2019-01-13', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-14', 'sold'),
('2019-01-19', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-21', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-22', 'sold'),
('2019-01-24', 'unsold'),
('2019-01-25', 'sold'),
('2019-01-29', 'sold'),
('2019-01-30', 'unsold'),
('2019-02-04', 'sold'),
('2019-02-05', 'sold'),
('2019-02-06', 'sold'),
('2019-02-11', 'sold'),
('2019-02-12', 'unsold'),
('2019-02-17', 'sold'),
('2019-02-18', 'unsold'),
('2019-02-19', 'unsold'),
('2019-02-20', 'sold')
;


DECLARE @want TABLE
(
    CallDate DATE,
    Status VARCHAR(10),
    PaidCall int, 
    Days_Since_Last_Paid_Call int
);

INSERT INTO @want (CallDate, Status, PaidCall, Days_Since_Last_Paid_Call)
values
('2019-01-01', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-02', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-04', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-08', 'sold', 1, NULL),
('2019-01-09', 'sold', 0, 1),
('2019-01-13', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-14', 'sold', 1, 6),
('2019-01-19', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-21', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-22', 'sold', 1, 8),
('2019-01-24', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-01-25', 'sold', 0, 3),
('2019-01-29', 'sold', 1, 7),
('2019-01-30', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-02-04', 'sold', 1, 6),
('2019-02-05', 'sold', 0, 1),
('2019-02-06', 'sold', 0, 2),
('2019-02-11', 'sold', 1, 7),
('2019-02-12', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-02-17', 'sold', 1, 6),
('2019-02-18', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-02-19', 'unsold', 0, NULL),
('2019-02-20', 'sold', 0, 3)

;
```

I would like to add the PaidCall flag in my table as shown in this table. Days_Since_Paid_Call is just for illustration purpose to explain how I am coming up with the PaidCall column.

Comment: In the DDL you have Status but What is Quote on the picture?

Comment: @nikeshpraj . . . This will be expensive because you need to use a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to iteratively process the data.  One method is using a recursive CTE:

```
with s as (
      select h.*, row_number() over (order by calldate) as seqnum
      from have h
      where status = 'sold'
     ),
     cte as (
      select calldate, seqnum, 1 as paidquote, calldate as paidquote_date
      from s
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select s.calldate, s.seqnum,
             (case when s.calldate > dateadd(day, 5, paidquote_date) then 1 else 0 end),
             (case when s.calldate > dateadd(day, 5, paidquote_date) then s.calldate else cte.paidquote_date end)
      from cte join
           s
           on s.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select h.calldate, h.status, coalesce(cte.paidquote, 0) as paidquote
from have h left join
     cte
     on h.calldate = cte.calldate
order by h.calldate;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f96aa93eee433321af6830687e7ad49) is a db<>fiddle.